# linux: how to change the owner into root

Tags: linux

I accidentally changed the owner of `/usr`. Now the owner of `/usr` becomes me, not `root`. So I can't use the command such as `sudo`. I want to change the owner of `/usr` back. I mean I want to change the owner of `/usr` into `root`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to know root password, you should be able to login as root and restore the permissions. `su` may also work:

```
$ su
[***enter root password***]
# chown root /usr
# chgrp root /usr
```

Comment: i restarted the system and I cant login now....

Comment: Try [booting in single-user mode](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) to repair the damage. If that doesn't work, proceed with Live CD.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Dmitry Grigoryev, sudo "*may refuse to give root priveleges to a process if the corresponding executable file can be modified by regular users.*"

Another solution is to live boot from a cd/ usb and use that environment to set the owner of /usr by mounting the hard drive and then changing it there with the command

```
chown root:root <path to the>/usr
```

inside the live boot.

Comment: `sudo` may refuse to give root priveleges to a process if the corresponding executable file can be modified by regular users. Running such files as root defeats `sudo`'s security model.